# Git Submodule checkout for downloaded git repository as an artifact

Tags: git, azure-devops, git-submodules

The scenario is related to the Azure DevOps pipeline. We are checking out the repo in one of the jobs and building the solution. Post archiving the repo+binaries, we are publishing that as an Artifact.

Now, this artifact is getting downloaded on another job (separate agent) and we want to check out the submodule (git submodule update) on this new agent without checking out the repo again.

Can anyone suggest something here? We tried git init/ git submodule init before git submodule update and nothing worked.

FYI.. the submodule update command works fine if we check out our repository.

Comment: Hi @Sandy, could you share the pipeline definition here? In addition, you want to add the download artifact on the new pipeline and without checking out the repo again, right?

Comment: Hi, Just checking in to see whether this issue is still blocking you now? Any update for this issue?

Answer (score 0):

We could checkout submodules via below cmd:

```
git -c http.https://<url of submodule repository>.extraheader="AUTHORIZATION: basic <BASE64_ENCODED_TOKEN_DESCRIBED_ABOVE>" submodule update --init --recursive
```

Please refer this [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/repos/pipeline-options-for-git?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml#checkout-submodules) for more details.